# syntax error at or near "Z" when trying to create materialized view

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have the following query:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW tk AS
SELECT * 
FROM base
WHERE ST_Contains(geo, POLYGON Z ((...some values ...)))
```

But I'm getting error:

```
syntax error at or near "Z"
```

the `geo` field is `geometry` field type

What is the problem and how to solve it ?

Comment: `PolygonZ` not `Polygon Z`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is missing the single quotes:

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE base (geo geometry);
INSERT INTO base VALUES ('POLYGONZ((1 0 0, 0 5 0, 5 5 0, 5 0 0, 1 0 0))');

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW tk AS
SELECT * FROM base
WHERE 
  ST_Contains (geo,'POLYGONZ((2.51 3.33 1,2.07 2.24 1,3.28 2.26 1,2.51 3.33 1))');

SELECT ST_AsText(geo) FROM tk;

                  st_astext                  
---------------------------------------------
 POLYGON Z ((1 0 0,0 5 0,5 5 0,5 0 0,1 0 0))
(1 Zeile)
```

**Note**: The documentation of [`ST_Contains`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html) does not mention anything about also computing the `Z` dimension in the function. Therefore we can assume that it is simply ignored and the query just takes `X` and `Y` into account.